# Bot Framework - return Image

Tags: c#, image, botframework

I use windows7 Professional and other Bot run without problem.
I want to return an image to my BOT, but the code suggested by Microsoft guide doesn't run

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

        Activity reply = activity.CreateReply( $" Hello");


        reply.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
        {
            ContentUrl = $"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a6/Bender_Rodriguez.png",
            ContentType = "image/png",
            Name = "Bender_Rodriguez.png"
        });

        await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
    }
    else
    {
        HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

I tried this code with Bot Emulator and got the following error:

[image]

Comment: Please refer this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38643808/downloading-file-pdf-image-from-using-microsoft-bot-framework

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialize the Attachments array.  In your code, it's null so the Add call is causing a NULL ref exception.

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

            Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($" Hello");

            reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();  //****** INIT

            reply.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
            {
                ContentUrl = $"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a6/Bender_Rodriguez.png",
                ContentType = "image/png",
                Name = "Bender_Rodriguez.png"
            });

            await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I ran into the same problem and couldn't figure out what is wrong for like 10 minutes. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these lines of code after reply activity initialization.

```
reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
reply.Recipient = activity.From;
reply.Type = "message";
```

You can refer this link for more details
[downloading file (pdf/image) from using Microsoft bot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38643808/downloading-file-pdf-image-from-using-microsoft-bot-framework)